# Incrementing variable increments before draw function runs

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new programmer using code sculptor with python 3. I have an animation project and one of the requirements is to change the background between two different settings 100 times

At the bottom, I've added print(i) to show what the problem with my code is. Basically, the "i" variable gets incremented, but it doesn't run the draw function, so the variable is incremented without the background changing. I've tried changing the positions of the draw function and nothing seems to be working. I am wondering if someone on this site could give me pointers on what to do in this situation. My overall goal is to run the program and have the background change as the train moves. You can see the program running by changing the values in the for loops to low values such as 1 and 1.

```
<pre>import simplegui
import time

def draw_handler(canvas):
    global x 
    global flag
    x = x+3
    flag = flag + 2
    if flag >= 320:
        x = x-930
        flag = -300

    canvas.draw_circle([550,50], 40, 4, "yellow", "yellow")
    points = [[0,500], [0,600], [600,600], [600,500]]
    canvas.draw_polygon(points, 1, "black", "sienna") 
    points2 = [[155+x,325], [155+x,450], [455+x,450], [455+x,325]]
    canvas.draw_polygon(points2, 1, "black", "deepskyblue")
    points3 = [[155+x,250],[155+x,325],[235+x,325],[235+x,250]]
    canvas.draw_polygon(points3, 1, "black", "deepskyblue")
    canvas.draw_circle([190+x,470], 35, 4, "dimgrey","lightgray")
    canvas.draw_circle([267+x,470], 35, 4, "dimgrey","lightgray")
    canvas.draw_circle([344+x,470], 35, 4, "dimgrey","lightgray")
    canvas.draw_circle([421+x,470], 35, 4, "dimgrey","lightgray")
    points4 = [[120+x,225],[120+x,255],[265+x,255],[265+x,225]]
    canvas.draw_polygon(points4, 1, "black", "black")
    points5 = [[425+x,235], [425+x,325], [445+x,325], [445+x,235]]
    canvas.draw_polygon(points5, 1, "black", "black")
    canvas.draw_line([410+x,230], [460+x, 230], 7, "black")
    canvas.draw_line([175+x,350], [427+x, 350], 2, "red")
    canvas.draw_line([175+x,350], [175+x, 420], 2, "red")
    canvas.draw_line([427+x,350], [427+x, 420], 2, "red")
    canvas.draw_line([175+x,420], [427+x, 420], 2, "red")

global color
color = ""
global y
global i
i = 0
for i in range(100):
    for i in range(20000):
        i = i + 10
        print(i)
        if i <= 10000:
            color = "aliceblue"
        elif i > 10000:
            color = "red"
        elif i > 20000:
            i = 0

frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 600, 600) 
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.set_canvas_background(color)
x = 0
flag = 0 
frame.start()</pre>
```

edit: Here is a direct link to the code in CodeSkulptor - https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user302_ZF0cMFUoOAK9PvH.py

Comment: You face the problem because you try to change color before you actually draw anything. You should change color during the drawing. Try this version of your code https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user302_b6qnxl3imaWNHy4_1.py.

Comment: @Poolka Thank you so much!